# Objective C How to check and see if object was chosen?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I am trying to write an if statement that checks an array of objects to see if a certain object exists (in this case the word, "NBC" in my array, "channel"). I'm new to this and I'm not sure how to do it in objective c. Please take a look at my code below:

```
if ([[self.channel objectAtIndex:path.row] containsObject: @"NBC"]) 

{
//Arguments
}
```

After I run it with this, the simulator crashes and gives this error: 2013-01-02 17:11:44.778 Master Detail Practice App[50056:207] -[__NSCFConstantString containsObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc698

I know my syntax or logic is probably off. Any help will be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: It's telling you that `self.channel[path.row]` is a string.  You probably meant to do `[self.channel containsObject:SomeString]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[self.channel objectAtIndex:path.row]` is returning you an `NSString` object.  You're then trying to send that `NSString` instance a `containsObject:` message, which it doesn't know what to do with.  Maybe you meant:

```
[self.channel objectAtIndex:path.row] isEqualToString:@"NBC"]
```

or

```
[self.channel containsObject:@"NBC"]
```

But without more context, it's hard to say.

Comment: perfect, the first example is exactly what i needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are pulling out the String from an array rather than checking the array for the String.  Try rewriting your code like this:

```
if ([self.channel containsObject: @"NBC"]) {
   //Arguments
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and that works fine but I don't want to just check and see if my array contains a certain object. I want to be able to see which object was selected by the "user" and use multiple if statements to determine what arguments need to be done depending on what object was chosen. Does that make sense?

Comment: In that case, see what @CarlNorum wrote above with the `isEqualToString` method.